# Can't get ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Connection.Local to work for 10.2.1

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.2, c#, arcgis-web-adf

Not sure what I'm missing. I'm trying to use the ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.ComReleaser and I can't get C# to recognize the ADF namespace. I can add the reference by going to Reference->Add ArcGIS Reference, but when I build the project I get the error: "The type or namespace name 'ADF' does not exist in the namespace 'ESRI.ArcGIS' (are you missing an assembly reference?)". I saw another post that said you have to add ...ADF.Connection.Local as a .NET reference, but when I try that approach it's not visible in the list, only ...ADF.Local.